# Google Apis Geocode inconsistencies in short_name (same language)

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google API Geocodes to retrieve the administratives levels from an address given. If I try with Valladolid, Spain ( http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Valladolid,Spain&language=en ) I get as administrative_area_level_2.short_name: VA.

```
{
"long_name": "Valladolid",
"short_name": "VA",
"types": [
"administrative_area_level_2",
"political"
]
},
```

But if I try with Seville,Spain ( http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Seville,Spain&language=en ) :

```
{
"long_name": "Seville",
"short_name": "Seville",
"types": [
"administrative_area_level_2",
"political"
]
},
```

the short name is Seville instead of SE.

Anybody knows how to skip this problem? I'm working with severals countries and some of them have this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say certainly, but this might be a data issue on the Google side. I suppose the administrative area level 2 for Valladolid has an abbreviated value stored in the database while administrative area level 2 for Sevilla doesn't have the abbreviated value stored, so Geocoding API uses the complete name.

You should send a feedback to Google. Open the Sevilla admin area level 2 in Google maps

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Seville/@37.5145054,-6.7170897,8z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0xd12f2dae16bd169:0x30463fd8c9fcbc0!8m2!3d37.3376829!4d-5.5617279

and click Send feedback as shown in my screenshot

[image]

I hope this helps!